# URGENT:Unable to takeoff drone automatically in real life(Navio2 with Ardupilot via MavROS)

Tags: ros-noetic, drone, ardupilot, automatic

I am currently working on a project that utilizes hand gestures to control the drone without GPS. I was able to arm the drone but cannot seem to make the drone take off after arming in real life. This is my first time doing such a project, so i am not sure what have i not done or is doing wrongly.

This is the code i used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from mavros_msgs.srv import CommandBool, SetMode
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped
from mavros_msgs.msg import State

class DroneController:
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('drone_controller', anonymous=True)

        self.current_state = State()
        self.rate = rospy.Rate(20.0)  # 20 Hz update rate

        self.local_pos_pub = rospy.Publisher('/mavros/setpoint_position/local', PoseStamped, queue_size=10)
        self.state_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/mavros/state', State, self.state_cb)

        # Create services
        self.arm_service = rospy.ServiceProxy('/mavros/cmd/arming', CommandBool)
        self.set_mode_service = rospy.ServiceProxy('/mavros/set_mode', SetMode)

        self.hover()

    def state_cb(self, msg):
        self.current_state = msg

    def arm(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Arming")
        return self.arm_service(True)

    def disarm(self):
        rospy.loginfo("Disarming")
        return self.arm_service(False)

    def set_mode(self, mode):
        rospy.loginfo(f"Setting mode to {mode}")
        return self.set_mode_service(custom_mode=mode)

    def hover(self):
        self.set_mode("ALT_HOLD")  # Change to ALT_HOLD mode for manual control if not already in ALT_HOLD mode
        rospy.sleep(2)

        # Arm the drone
        if not self.current_state.armed:
            self.arm()

        # Set the initial position to the current position
        initial_pose = PoseStamped()
        initial_pose.pose.position.z = 0.0  # Start at ground level
        for _ in range(100):
            self.local_pos_pub.publish(initial_pose)
            self.rate.sleep()

        # Gradually increase altitude for takeoff
        takeoff_pose = PoseStamped()
        takeoff_pose.pose.position.z = 2.0  # Set the desired altitude for takeoff
        rospy.loginfo("Automatic takeoff initiated...")
        for _ in range(100):
            self.local_pos_pub.publish(takeoff_pose)
            takeoff_pose.pose.position.z += 0.02  # Increase altitude gradually
            self.rate.sleep()

        # Hover
        rospy.loginfo("Hovering in ALT_HOLD mode...")
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            # Adjust altitude or other control parameters as needed
            self.local_pos_pub.publish(takeoff_pose)
            self.rate.sleep()

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    drone_controller = DroneController()

    # Spin the ROS node
    rospy.spin()
```

Thank you in advance!